# Is set of all RE languages $\subseteq\\$ $\Sigma^{*}?$

Tags: formal-languages, computability, regular-languages, context-free, enumeration

We know that any languages $\subseteq\\\\$ $\Sigma^{*}.$ Because any language collection of string over alphabet. And we know that set of all languages is $2^{\Sigma^{*}}$ which doesn't $\subsetneq\\\\$ $\Sigma^{*}.$ But I have couple of smalls confusion  are that

$A.$ Set of all regular languages $\{L_1,L_2,L_3................\}$ is $\subseteq\\\\$ $\Sigma^{*}$ or not?

$B.$ Set of all context free languages $\{L_1,L_2,L_3................\}$ is $\subseteq\\\\$ $\Sigma^{*}$ or not?

$C.$ Set of all recursive enumerable languages $\{L_1,L_2,L_3................\}$ is $\subseteq\\\\$ $\Sigma^{*}$ or not?

$D.$ Any not recursive enumerable language $L$ is $\subseteq\\\\$ $\Sigma^{*}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\Sigma^*$ consists of all words over $\Sigma$.

A language over $\Sigma$ is not a word over $\Sigma$. Hence no language is a member of $\Sigma^*$, and no set of languages is a subset of $\Sigma^*$.

Comment: "no language is a member of Σ∗" is right but how  set of languages is a subset of Σ∗?

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo.

Comment: any not Recursive enumerable language subset of $\Sigma^{*}\$

Comment: any non recursive enumerable language is subset of $\Sigma^*$?

Comment: Any language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$, in particular, any non recursively enumerable one.